# Adobe Flash Player Settings panel display behind divs

Tags: html, css, adobe, flash

I am unable to click on "Allow" button in my Adobe Flash Player Settings panel that pop's up because half of it is hidden behind divs making it "unclickable".

I tried setting negative z-indices on the divs that are overlaying it and I also tried giving a prositive z-index to the div holding the Flash Player Settings panel.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set the wmode parameter for your flash player to opaque.

Comment: Tried that... doesn't seem to take effect. I tried stripping the rendered html and found that the panel becomes clickable if I extend the width of the div that is housing it...

Comment: there's a minimum size your flash needs to be to display the settings box properly. is your swf really small?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [swfObject2](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for embedding.